# How to put my material ui app drawer below my header

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[Material UI sidebar is fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEaEP.png) <= This is an image for reference of the issue that I am getting

I want my app drawer to start after my header paragraph finishes but right now the app drawer is fixed and is overlapping with the header.

In my App.js I have included my two components as below -

```
<Header/>
<SideNav/>
```

I am using Material UI with React JS.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a toolbar, since your Paragraph is a Header

https://material-ui.com/pt/api/toolbar/